# What are the origins of Rodan in "Godzilla: King of the Monsters"?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-king-of-monsters

In [*Godzilla: King of the Monsters* (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3741700/), they didn't explain Rodan's origin too well. Gidorha's origin was explained to be an extraterrestrial. Though Rodan was hibernating in the volcano, he barely had any special attributes like Godzilla having an atomic breath or Mothra being able to shoot silk. Coming from a volcano, you would think he'd have fire breath at least.  What are Rodan's origins and special powers?

Comment: You're asking 2 distinct questions here, one asking about Rodan's origin and another asking if Rodan should have some special ability/attack. please choose one to keep in this question and edit out the other one and ask it as a separate question

Comment: @Memor-X I think the two questions are interrelated enough, though. It was asked a little unluckily as well as in a way seemingly speculating about what powers Rodan *should* have. And maybe the asker wasn't particularly attentive to the film where he should have seen any possible "special powers". But in its current form it might be okay, asking generally for Rodan's background and what he is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *King Of The Monsters*, Rodan was awakened by an accumulation of volcanic gas.  Rodan's origin goes back to the 1956 film *Rodan*, when he was a Pteranodon that lived deep underground and was mutated from exposure to radiation, and grew to gigantic size.

Rodan possesses several abilities, including:

- Durability - Rodan is the only monster not affected by Godzilla's atomic breath.
- Flight Speed - Rodan can avoid attacks by flying away from them.
- Wind/Radioactive Heat Breath (not used in this movie) - In Rodan's first movie, he could emit a beam of wind to knock opponents down.  After that first movie, the wind was changed to a radioactive blast of heat.
- Thunderclap - Rodan, specific to King Of The Monsters, can generate a tremendous amount of wind by flapping it's wings in the direction of an enemy.

Comment: im confuse about his origin of Rodan if he was Pteranodon in King of the monsters in 2019 he flew into the volcano that rebirth him as new body shape and appearance of a normal pteranodon. But ALSO the ability of thunderclap wasn't used on Ghidorah or Mothra.

Comment: The first scene with Rodan, he uses fire breath on the city of people doesn't he?

Comment: No he didn’t in 2019 he had no fire breath